# Django: strange IntegrityError upon saving a ModelFormset form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save a couple ModelFormset forms, but am running into an IntegrityError.  Here is the code:

```
    billing_formset = BillingFormSet(request.POST,prefix='billing')
    cc_formset = CCFormSet(request.POST,prefix='cc')

    if billing_formset.is_valid() and cc_formset.is_valid():
        bp = UserBillingProfile()
        cc = UserCreditCard()
        for form in billing_formset.forms:
            billing_profile = form.save(commit=False)
            billing_profile.user = request.user
            bp = billing_profile.save()
        for form in cc_formset.forms:
            cc = form.save(commit=False)
            cc.billing_profile = bp
            cc = form.save()
```

This code caused the following code:

> IntegrityError at [url removed]
>   (1048, "Column 'user_billing_profile_id' cannot be null")

---

EDIT:  Here is some iterative code that also fixes my typo.  I'm running into basically the same problem.

```
        billing_profile_form = billing_formset.forms[0]
        cc_form = cc_formset.forms[0]

        unsaved_billing_profile = billing_profile_form.save(commit=False)
        user_billing_profile = unsaved_billing_profile.save()

        unsaved_cc = cc_form.save(commit=False)
        unsaved_cc.user_billing_profile = user_billing_profile
        cc = unsaved_cc.save()
```

Problem line gives:  "Cannot assign None: "UserCreditCard.user_billing_profile" does not allow null values."  It seems unsaved_billing_profile.save() is returning null?  Why?

---

This is kind of crazy; everything seems to be right.  I don't get any errors when saving the billing profile.  Any ideas on what I should check?  Things seem to be going wrong in the second loop, where bp apparently has a value of None.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not the answer, but there's a logic problem in your code: each of the instances of `cc` will be assigned to the *final* instance of `bp`, because you iterate through them separately.

Comment: True... I've restricted the maximum input form count 1, though, and made that cleaner by doing it non-iteratively.  I posted the iterative code because there seemed to be something wrong with the non-iterative code.

Answer (score 0):

This means you are trying to save a model instance with user_billing_profile set to None, looks like you are calling "billing_profile" instead of "user_billing_profile".

The "save" method returns None every time commit=False isn't specified. you should instead call something like this:

```
billing_profile.save()
bp = billing_profile.instance
```

Comment: Also true (oops!).  Fixed that, but the billing_profile.save() call seems to make bp null.  Posting some iterative code so it's clear that the loops aren't causing problems.

Comment: I have modified this response, hope it helps.